# How to download file automatically from a pop up using Selenium in PHP?

Tags: php, selenium

I want to download the file automatically whenever there is a pop up dialog for the same. I found out that it is possible by using Selenium.

I have installed and setup Selenium on my system and then downloaded this from GitHub:

```
https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver
```

I am not much familiar with Selenium.

Comment: Do you mean the browser popup or the website pop up?

Comment: @Farkie Browser pop up

Comment: How are you controlling Selenium - with something like CodeCeption?

Comment: Oh, you're using facebook's webdriver. I'd suggest using Codeception, as it's even more abstract, and make's much more sense to a newcomer.

Comment: i have just installed it, i don't know what to do next

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this? https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-download-a-file-with-webdriver